# Do I need multiple Jetbrains IDE's or can I collect them into one?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

How do I collect multiple Jetbrains IDE's into one, like I do with Eclipse using plugins? I do Java, Ruby and C/C++ and don't won't a single IDE installed for every programming language.

Comment: I believe that you can install for instance PHP or Ruby Jetbrains plugins into Intellij Ultimate, which should provide the same functionality as PhpStorm/RubyMine. However since CLion is fairly new IDE its functionality is not yet available as a plugin for IntelliJ, so you must install it as a separate application for now (see comments in [this blogpost](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/04/clion-1-0-has-finally-arrived/)).

Answer (score 3):

JetBrains provides IntelliJ Idea for Java and Ruby development and for C/C++ it provides, CLion IDE. So it is not possible to collect multiple IDEs into one.